# Migration of JPA 1.0 to JPA 2.0 web application which is using spring2.0 struts 2.0 hibernate 3 project

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee, struts2

Hi All hopes doing well,

I wants to migrate my web application which is using JPA 1.0 to JPA 2.0.

My Project Tech stack as.....

```
Hibernate3.0
Struts 2.0
Spring 2.0
weblogic 10.3.6
Java1.6
eclipse LUNA 4.4.1
```

Kindly suggest me what all changes required in my current projet set up.
I have tried by changing hinernate jar file but havn't got any success.Alse gone through                                                                                           varius post  but not working for me

Specially jar files.
Below jar files used in my project...
Any help highly aprecited.

my jar files...

```
ejb3-persistence.jar
hibernate-annotations.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations.jar
hibernate-entitymanager.jar
hibernate3.jar

hibernate-annotations.jar
 hibernate-commons-annotations.jar
 hibernate-entitymanager.jar
 hibernate3.jar
 spring-agent.jar
  spring-mock.jar
 spring-test.jar
  spring.jar
```

Thanks in advance.
 Still wondering for solution but unable to do that, please help me out.
Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: srtuts related jar files..struts-menu-2.4.3.jar
struts.jar
struts2-core-2.0.11.jar
struts2-scope-plugin-1.0.4.jar
struts2-spring-plugin-2.0.11.jar
struts2gwtplugin-0.2.jar

Comment: Do you got an Exception ? This question as it is now is a nonsense. Upgrade your struts jars to 2.3.16.3, upgrade your hibernate jars to 4.x. Good luck.

Comment: thanx Andrea for your responce.While upgrading struts2-core jar to 2.3.15.1,gettings compilation problem. I havn't found 2.3.16.3 version for download.

Comment: http://struts.apache.org/downloads.html

Comment: while upgrading hibernate to 4.x getting some error, by additions of specific jar its get resolved but at last the following error came.java.lang.AbstractMethodError: getValidationMode
 at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:633)
 at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:73)
 at weblogic.deployment.BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.initializeEntityManagerFactory(BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:393)
 at weblogic.deployment.BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.

Comment: Use Maven that keeps the versions aligned for you, or check carefully the dependencies of all the jars needed manually

Comment: following jars working fine for JPA 1.0 hibernate-annotations.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations.jar
hibernate-entitymanager.jar
hibernate3.jar

Comment: project also contains------ejb3-persistence.jar

Comment: Project having ANT configred,I hope its not alloud to use Maven.So tring to figured out correct Jars.

Comment: Thanx Andrea , I find all jars version 2.3.16.3 from suggested link.

Comment: As mentioned by Andra, use Maven. It would be a good first step to set up a Maven project and have your current applications dependencies managed that way. Then further upgrades will be a lot easier, well from the dependency side.

Comment: any one can help me i am getting following error while migrating JPA 1.0 to 2.0.......Dec 1, 2014 6:31:31 PM org.hibernate.util.XMLHelper$ErrorLogger error
SEVERE: Error parsing XML: XML InputStream(5) cvc-complex-type.3.1: Value '2.0' of attribute 'version' of element 'entity-mappings' is not valid with respect to the corresponding attribute use. Attribute 'version' has a fixed value of '1.0'.

Comment: does any one having solution for the............Caused By: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.3.1: Value '2.0' of attribute 'version' of element 'entity-mappings' is not valid with respect to the corresponding attribute use. Attribute 'version' has a fixed value of '1.0'.

Comment: I am unable to identify the correct jar for above problem..

Comment: I am using following jar.......commons-collections-3.1.jar,dom4j-1.6.1.jar,hibernate-commons-annotations-3.2.0.Final.jar,hibernate-core-3.6.7.Final.jar,hibernate-entitymanager.jar,hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar,javassist.jar,jsr250-api-1.0.jar,jta-1.1.jar,log4j-1.2.16.jar,ojdbc14.jar,slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar,slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar....any one can suggest me whats the wrong...any help highly appriciated......